# Yii2 insert query with bindparam for sql injection

Tags: yii2

I want use but not work please help me.

```
$sql = Yii::$app->db("INSERT INTO posts(name) VALUES(:name)");
$sql->bindValues([':name' => 'John']);
$sql->execute();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try create command exceute

```
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand('INSERT INTO posts(name) VALUES(:name)')
          ->bindValues([':name' => 'John'])->execute();
```

Comment: $sql = Yii::$app->db->createCommand("INSERT INTO posts(name) VALUES(:name)");
$sql->bindValues([':name' => 'John']);
$sql->execute();